# Working C# code converted to Powershell results in SocketException

Tags: azure, powershell, http, asp.net-core, azure-api-management

I have the following C# console app which successfully calls an HTTP Post endpoint:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://DomainOne.azure-api.net");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "8b17badbbfe44e9e933453a8b4d8fc85");

        StringContent stringContent = new StringContent("\"hi\"", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");            
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = httpClient.PostAsync("integration/api/Result/CompanyOne", stringContent);
        HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;

        var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

This is the equivalent Powershell script I'm trying to use:

```
$httpClient = New-Object 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'
$httpClient.BaseAddress = New-Object 'System.Uri'('https://DomainOne.azure-api.net')
$httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "8b17badbbfe44e9e933453a8b4d8fc85");

$stringContent = New-Object 'System.Net.Http.StringContent'('"hi"', [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8, 'application/json')
$task = $httpClient.PostAsync('integration/api/Result/CompanyOne', $stringContent)
$response = $task.Result

$content = $response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
```

However the `$task` object contains the following:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. 
---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. 
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

The endpoint is hosted in our dev Azure environment behind API Management, and the action method/controller looks like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ResultController : ControllerBase
{                           
    [Route("{providerName}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public Task<bool> ReceiveMessage(HL7Message message)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

Here are the protocol settings in Azure API Management:
[image: Protocols]

Why am I getting the `SocketException` in Powershell but not in C#, and how can I get it to work in Powershell?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with tls negotiation. Can you verify what tls version you are using? Can your force tls 1.2 ?

Comment: @AdminOfThings I think it's using TLS 1.2. I updatd my question with a screenshot of the protocol settings in APIM.

Comment: Try adding a line of code at the front of your script to specifically set the SecvicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to TLS1.2.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_ServicePointManager_SecurityProtocol

Comment: @RickRainey thankyou! That worked! If you write up an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Please be sure to accept @RickRainey's answer if he posts anything. I posted just so that we have an answer in case Rick decides not to post anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Rick Rainey's helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2157294/rick-rainey), you can force the TLS version by adding the line of code below before the HTTP call:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

I believe this to be a limitation of the .NET version being used. Any version below .NET 4.6 will default to using a TLS version that is not 1.2.